# Getting multiple malformed cookies via c#

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

After a long day in searching and attempts I could not find a solution for my problem - getting multiple "Set-Cookie" headers.
I was trying to get them via Headers["Set-Cookie"] but it contains the only the first cookie.
Then my next try was to get them via Cookies (which is always with Count 0 and the purpose because I think they are malformed). 
Here is the code to the last sample:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var cookiesCount = response.Cookies.Count;
```

And these are the cookies:

```
Set-Cookie:vjfmrii=67ea0de93a423ab17d168ee8327617b0
Set-Cookie:alpocjengi=dcf10w329x5d7e503ffb9f28123c7492f1c2deb4
Set-Cookie:vjfmrii=4abf7b9e97fff1a61fbcf5e11899ce71
```

Before I began, I thought that this would be one of the easiest parts, but unfortunately I was wrong. These cookies which have the same names and have several... have left me devastated.
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The built in .Net libraries are a bit difficult to use in my experience. I'd highly recommend you take a look at RestSharp and see if it will work for you. If so it's a lot simpler and more intuitive to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx) to your request when you make it or the cookies will not be added to the response. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298(v=vs.95).aspx.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // <-- Add this

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var cookiesCount = response.Cookies.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll read the article carefully. I cannot believe that this line of code bothering me so many hours. Thank you again!